# If conjugation by a matrix preserves the matrix norm then the matrix must be conformal?

Tags: normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, symmetry, conformal-geometry, similar-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real invertible matrix, and suppose that $\| X\|^2=\| AXA^{-1}\|^2$ for every $n \times n$ real matrix $X$.

Is it true that $A$ must be conformal?

(It is easy to see that conformal matrices $A$ satisfy this).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "conformal" matrix? Does it mean that $\langle Ax, Ay\rangle = \langle x, y\rangle$ for all vectors $x, y$, or something else?

Comment: No, these will be isometries. I meant for $\langle Ay, Ax\rangle = \lambda(A) \langle y, x\rangle$, where $\lambda(A)$ is some constant factor which depends only on $A$. In other words, I allow for scalings.

Comment: Yes, of course. I should've thought of that as well.

Comment: If $A=UP$ is the polar decomposition of $A$, with $U$ unitary and $P$ Hermitian positive definite, then $P$ satisfies the same property. Let $V$ be unitary such that $P=V^*DV$, with $D$ is diagonal. Then $\|V^*XV\|=\|X\|=\|PXP^{-1}\|=\|DVXV^*D^{-1}\|$. So, for all matrices $X$ we have that $\|X\|=\|DXD^{-1}\|$. Now take $X$ to be all zeros except for the entry at $(i,j)$, where it has a $1$. We have that $\|X\|=1$, while $\|DXD^{-1}\|$ is the quotient of the $i$-th and $j$-th eigenvalues. Therefore, $P=cI$ for some scalar $c$. Then $A$ is conformal.